# Eagerly fetch ManyToOne causes additional queries when not found

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

## Scenario

I've got two Tables (`TABLE_ONE` and `TABLE_TWO`, for full sources please see my example project linked at the bottom) which are abstraction from a legacy DB (without primary or foreign keys or any constraints) which I only **read** from and which I can **not change** at all. These two tables are linked together via an unidirectional `ManyToOne` (it actually *may* be a `OneToOne`) relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_STRING", referencedColumnName = "SOME_STRING", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_INTEGER", referencedColumnName = "SOME_INTEGER", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_INDEX", referencedColumnName = "SOME_INDEX", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private TableTwoEntity tableTwoEntity;
```

On `TABLE_ONE` I've got a `NamedQuery` which `LEFT JOIN FETCH`es `TABLE_TWO` and Hibernate (4.3.x) creates a query as expected:

```
SELECT
  tableoneen0_.SOME_INDEX   AS SOME_IND1_0_0_,
  tableoneen0_.SOME_INTEGER AS SOME_INT2_0_0_,
  tableoneen0_.SOME_STRING  AS SOME_STR3_0_0_,
  tabletwoen1_.SOME_INDEX   AS SOME_IND1_1_1_,
  tabletwoen1_.SOME_INTEGER AS SOME_INT2_1_1_,
  tabletwoen1_.SOME_STRING  AS SOME_STR3_1_1_,
  tableoneen0_.SOME_DATA    AS SOME_DAT4_0_0_,
  tabletwoen1_.SOME_DATA    AS SOME_DAT4_1_1_
FROM TABLE_ONE tableoneen0_
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO tabletwoen1_ ON
    tableoneen0_.SOME_INDEX = tabletwoen1_.SOME_INDEX AND
    tableoneen0_.SOME_INTEGER = tabletwoen1_.SOME_INTEGER AND
    tableoneen0_.SOME_STRING = tabletwoen1_.SOME_STRING
WHERE tableoneen0_.SOME_DATA = ?
```

## Problem

The problem is, when there is no row in `TABLE_TWO` for an entry in `TABLE_ONE`, Hibernate generates **additional**, useless (imo) queries for each case (because it won't find an entry anyway):

```
SELECT
  tabletwoen0_.SOME_INDEX   AS SOME_IND1_1_0_,
  tabletwoen0_.SOME_INTEGER AS SOME_INT2_1_0_,
  tabletwoen0_.SOME_STRING  AS SOME_STR3_1_0_,
  tabletwoen0_.SOME_DATA    AS SOME_DAT4_1_0_
FROM TABLE_TWO tabletwoen0_
WHERE tabletwoen0_.SOME_INDEX = ? AND tabletwoen0_.SOME_INTEGER = ? AND tabletwoen0_.SOME_STRING = ?
```

## Goal

Because of these addtional select statements the performance of my application decreases significantly (hours instead of minutes), so I want to get rid of them. So, how do I tell Hibernate to **not** create these additional select statements?

## Additional Information

- Hibernate version 4.3.x (provided via Wildfly 9.0.1)

  - I've tried various 5.x versions in my standalone example project as well, with the same result. So I think it might be some wanted behaviour.
- The problem also seems to be independent of the database in use, because the original tables are in a DB2 and I've also tried with SQL-Server and HSQLDB
- The example project can be found here: https://github.com/mratzer/stackoverflow-001

Comment: You fix your database, and remove the NotFound annotation. If your database was in a sane state, Hibernate would **assume** that the row refered by those columns exist. Otherwise, they should be null. So, remove the references to unexisting rows, add a foreign key constraint to never, ever be able again to delete a row without deleting its references, and to never, ever be able to create a reference to to an unexisting row. Hibernate is forced to execute the query because, even though there is a reference to a row, that row  might not exist. So it has to check.

Comment: @JBNizet the thing is, I **can't** change anything in this DB because I'm in no position to do so. Actually this problem occured while migrating data into a new, (hopefully) sane DB. I'd love to add _primary keys_, _foreign keys_, etc., but as I said, I can't. :(

Comment: Then you'll have to suffer for the poor database design/state.